# Creating Apache Kafka docker image with some configurations

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-iot-edge

Currently after I deploy Kafka to a machine, I need to run the following commands so it can be configured correctly:

```
docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181
docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --create --topic new-project --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic new-project
```

The problem is that i'm deploying this to a machine that does have `Docker Run` so I can no longer configure it.

In order to get around this, I'm trying to create a custom Kafka image that already have these configurations.

So I created a `dockerfile` that pull the image and run these configurations but that doesn't work because `docker` isn't available inside the `dockerfile`. I get the following error when I try to create the image: `/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found`.

This is how the `dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2

RUN docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181
RUN docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --create --topic new-project --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
RUN docker run --net=azure-iot-edge --rm confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2 kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic new-project
```

Anyone faced a similar issue and can offer some guidance?

Comment: Get the tools from confluent.io or kafka.apache.org and run them directly.  They don't specifically require Docker, especially the administrative commands you're looking at.

Comment: (it's worth updating to 5.3.1, 5.1.2 was released quite a while ago)

Comment: It would be useful if you edit your question with what you're trying to achieve, rather than _how_ you're trying to achieve it. `docker run` is just a way to invoke a tool inside the container. Where are you running docker? Are you just trying to pre-create a topic when you deploy your Kafka cluster?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Yes, I want the topic to exist when the container starts up. Is this possible? I'm trying to avoid Docker run because this require manual intervention and I'm trying to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

`docker` is not part of the base image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2`
If you really need to use Docker insider Docker, suggest to start with [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker)

However, from what you say:

> after I deploy Kafka to a machine, I need to run the following commands so
>   it can be configured correctly

I guess that you first want to run Docker container (deploy) of Kafka:

`docker run --net=azure-iot-edge -d --name cp_kafka confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.2`

and then execute the configuration commands (configure):

`docker exec -i cp_kafka kafka-topics --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181`

...